# Can't resolve host using Python Elasticsearch client

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using the [Python Elasticsearch Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/). When using like this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(['http://10.20.30.40:8888/'])
res = es.search(index='my_index', body=self.build_body())
```

all good! I can have my `res` perfectly.

However, I created an alias and mapped my elasticsearch endpoint:

`http://10.20.30.40:8888` ---> `http://foo.bar.com/search`

When accessing by browser or curl both work perfectly. But I can't make it working with this python client:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['http://foo.bar.com/search'])
res = es.search(index='my_index', body=self.build_body())
```

This raises a:

`TransportError(404, u'index_not_found_exception', u'no such index')`

Same result when:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'http://foo.bar.com/search'}])
```

Does any one already faced some issue like this?

**UPDATE:**

Could not make this working. So, what is working for me is:

```
u = urljoin(...)
r = requests.get(u, data=...)
```

Comment: How did you call the alias of your `my_index` index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just faced that same problem again. Turns out that, if you don't specify a port, es will assign `9200` automatically. So, the correct form is:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['http://foo.bar.com/search'], port=80)
```